# How to sum numbers from selected phrases? (sas, sql)

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to sum up the numbers from the text below:

```
Kwota=237 + Kwota=30.87 + Kwota=292.74 + Kwota=292.74 + Kwota=300.87
```

that is:

**Kwota=1154,22**

In the example there are 5 phrases but their number may vary.

**text:**

```
[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: Audi A 6, Kwota=237, Cena =123],[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: Volvo, Kwota=30.87, Cena =10],[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: VW Golf, Kwota=292.74, Cena =134],[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: VW Golf, Kwota=292.74, Cena =134],[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: Porche, Kwota=300.87, Cena =152]
```

Comment: That looks like JSON or XML that should first be properly parsed into a data set and then summarized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl regular expressions to find the `kwota=<number>` pieces, extract the number text using a matching group, and `input` function to convert the text to a number that can be accumulated in a sum or total variable.

Example:

```
data have;
length text $2000;
text = catx(',',
  '[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: Audi A 6, Kwota=237, Cena =123]'
, '[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: Volvo, Kwota=30.87, Cena =10]'
, '[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: VW Golf, Kwota=292.74, Cena =134]'
, '[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: VW Golf, Kwota=292.74, Cena =134]'
, '[Forma sprzedazy=leasing, auto: Porche, Kwota=300.87, Cena =152]'
);
output;
text = 'Nothing here';
output;
run;

data want;
  length kwota_total 8;

  set have;

  rxid = prxparse ('/kwota=(\d+\.?\d+)/i');

  start = 1;
  stop = length(text);

  do while (_n_);
    call prxnext (rxid, start, stop, text, position, length);
    if position < 1 then leave;

    kwota_total = sum(kwota_total, input (prxposn(rxid,1,text), best32.));
  end;
  drop rxid start stop position length;
run;
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you are reading from a text file directly, you could use an INPUT statement with character based column pointer control such as

```
  ... in a loop on a single line ...
    INPUT @'Kwota=' amount @;
    total = sum(total,amount);
```